# Temporal dead zone with let in for-loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, ecmascript-6

We can use `let` statements in `for` loops, with multiple variable assignments, for example:

```
for (let x = 0, y = 0; x < 10; ++ x);
```

However, we start getting discrepancies in implementations if we reference one variable from another; the following results in working code in Chrome, but a ReferenceError in Firefox:

```
for (let x = 0, y = x; x < 10; ++ x);
```

Firefox seems not to assign `x` to `y` under after the entire expression has been parsed, whereas Chrome does it immediately. Note that the following works in both browsers (the same statement outside of a `for` block):

```
let x = 0, y = x; // x = 0, y = 0
```

It seems as if Firefox's implementation is incorrect (especially after considering the case outside the `for` block), but what does the ES6 specification say about this? Is this something that needs to be (or has already) been reported?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox's `let` is an old non-standard implementation. The best place to look is http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/. Assuming you are on Firefox Stable (43), not that it is currently listed has having zero support for ES6 `let`.